# TypeError: window.parent.updatepic is not a function when i try to access function from iframe to his window's parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe inside my page, inside this iframe I am loading a page that has this Javascript code:

```
<script>
    var ready;
    ready = function() {
        window.parent.updatepic("#{@user.photo_url.to_s}")
    };
    $(document).ready(ready);
    $(document).on('page:load', ready);
</script>
```

The page which contains my iframe has a script below:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
  function updatepic(pic){
    $("#image").attr("src", pic);
  }
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

As you can see with this line in the first code sample above:

```
 window.parent.updatepic("#{@user.photo_url.to_s}")
```

I tried to call the `updatepic` function from inside the iframe, but I get an error in the console:

```
TypeError: window.parent.updatepic is not a function
```

I can't find or understand what I'm doing wrong here ? Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `updatepic` method in the parent window is wrapped inside a closure (the function you are assigning to the `ready` variable). So the function isn't available in the global `window` namespace.

Move the definition of `updatepic` outside of the function being assigned to `ready`.

Comment: hi @PascalZajac please there is a way to access to updatepic() without moving its definition ? i need to do it inside jquery closure

Comment: It makes no sense to define a function inside the `ready` callback if you need to access it from other places. The point of a closure is to avoid leaking functions/variables into the global namespace. In this case, you *need* the function to be in the global namespace.

Comment: i does same search yesterday and i found exactly as what do you say now. thank you for help :)